# ionic routing redirect to root on web server but not on local

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

On ionic angular type project
I build routes :

```
{
    path: 'foo',
    component: FooComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'foo',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  { path: '**', component: FooComponent},
```

Everything is ok on local `ionic serve`

But when I build `ionic build --prod` and upload "www" folder on web server (OVH),
the website redirect every url to the root url "https://example.com/test/"

When i try to go to "https://example.com/test/foo" I get "https://example.com/test/"

There is no .htaccess in "test" folder, I already have an Angular project on this web server and no problem with routing system.

Comment: I think you need to add --base-href /test/ to your build command

Comment: alrdy have `"baseHref": "/test/","deployUrl": "/test/",`

Comment: Is that specified in the angular config or in the command itself?

Comment: Not the problem because I get no 404 errors

Comment: After build my index.html contains
`<base href="/foo/">` and each src script or css start with /foo/